# About django calendar error

Tags: django

I have some errors : How can I do?, Why can't I import calendar? 
I'm using import calendar. Is that Correct? 
this is the error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://articles/month
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TypeError 
Exception Value: month() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
```

this is on admin error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://dev1.so2.co.jp/ihttest/ihttcs_test/admin/auth/user/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Could not import tcsarticle.views.calendar. View is not callable.
```

this is my views.py:

```
def month(request, year, month, change=None):
    year, month = int(year), int(month)
    if change in ("next", "prev"):
        now, mdelta = date(year, month, 15), timedelta(days=31)
        if change == "next":   mod = mdelta
        elif change == "prev": mod = -mdelta
        year, month = (now+mod).timetuple()[:2]
    article = calendar.Calendar()

    month_days = tcsarticle.itermonthdays(year, month)
    nyear, nmonth, nday = time.localtime()[:3]
    lst = [[]]
    week = 0

    for day in month_days:
        entries = current = False   # are there entries for this day; current day?
        if day:
            entries = User.objects.filter(date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day)
            if day == nday and year == nyear and month == nmonth:
                current = True
        lst[week].append((day, entries, current))
        if len(lst[week]) == 7:
            lst.append([])
            week += 1
    return render_to_response("month.html", dict(year=year, month=month,user=request.user,
month_days=lst, mname=mnames[month-1]))
```

This is the urls.py:

```
url(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/(prev|next)/$", "article.views.month"),
url(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "article.views.month"),
url(r"^month/$", "article.views.month"),
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar.py in the same directory as that views.py file?

Comment: No, don't have , I did not know a calendar.py！！

Comment: What's your urls.py file look like?

Comment: Ok, this is the urls.py:   url(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/(prev|next)/$", "article.views.month"),url(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "article.views.month"),url(r"^month/$", "article.views.month"),

Answer (score 0):

Change your urls.py to the following code. You should also read up on [captured url parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters).

```
url(r"^month/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(prev|next)/$", "article.views.month"),
url(r"^month/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/$", "article.views.month"),
```

You can't have that last line in your urls.py file because it's referencing the view `article.views.month` which requires at least 2 parameters (month and year), while that URL will pass no parameters into it.

Comment: Was this the answer? If so, can you mark it as such?

Comment: Mark my answer as the answer to your question.